# Android WebRTC SDK change video resolution dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, sdk, webrtc, screen-resolution

Does it possible to change video resolution dynamically by checking  network state or video stream latency or how to get network speed. Can you advice some solution to reach this.

Comment: Normally, this is one of the built-in features of WebRTC. Note that changing resolution is only one (and quite coarse) ways of matching the optimal bandwidth. You can tune the settings for bias that prioritize latency or quality.